# Delta H of reaction and finding delta h of components?

Tags: thermodynamics

$\Delta H$ for the reaction below is −126 kJ
$$\ce{2Na2O2(s) + 2 H2O(l) ->4 NaOH(s) + O2 (g)}$$
What is the amount of heat released by the reaction of 25.0 gram of $\ce{Na2O2}$ with water?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. This question looks like a homework question. Please provide us with your thoughts on the question or what you have tried so that we can provide more specific help. We are not a homework completion service. See our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Loosely put, enthalpy is the change in heat of a given reaction.  We see input of two moles of sodium peroxide to give a mole of oxygen in the balanced equation.  (What are the reduced and oxidized species?)  You have a mass of sodium peroxide input, you know how many moles that is, and you know the one equivalent of reaction requires two moles of sodium peroxide.  You then know the heat released.